# Aquisition date of digital globe imagery, Image Metadata File

Tags: qgis, metadata, maxar-digitalglobe

It might sound strange but I can't seem to find the acquisition date of images I acquired from digital globe. In the metadata file I only find the date the images were sent to me. I am using QGIS.

Where do I need to look for the acquisition date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The acquisition date can be read from the `.IMD` file. Open the file using a decent text editor (Notepad+ or Textpad for example, not regular Notepad) and look for the line called `earliestAcqTime`, which specifies the acquisition time in GMT / Zulu time.

Often, the acquisition date will also be stated in the filename. For example `13JUN12152735-M2AS_R1C1-054329948010_01_P001.TIF` is a WorldView-2 file that I have. The image was acquired in 2013 (the first two numbers in the filename), June (the three letters), 12th of the month (the next two numbers) at 15:27:35 (the last six numbers). Making the naming convention something along the lines of `YYMMDDHHMMSS`.